# Mutually recursive datatype declaration with Haskell Z3 API

Tags: haskell, z3, smt

I'm attempting to use this Haskell package:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3

which is a wrapper of the Z3 C API, to work with mutually recursive datatypes.  As a test, I am attempting to convert the following SMT2 script to a Haskell function.

```
(declare-datatypes () ((X (a (y Y)) ac)
                  (Y (b (x X)) bc)))

(declare-const a_v (X))
(declare-const b_v (Y))

(assert (= a_v (a b_v)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Currently, the closest I can figure out how to get is:

```
mutuallyRecursive :: IO (Result, Maybe Model)
mutuallyRecursive = evalZ3 mutuallyRecursive'
    where
        mutuallyRecursive' :: Z3 (Result, Maybe Model)
        mutuallyRecursive' = do
            x' <- mkStringSymbol "X"
            y' <- mkStringSymbol "Y"
            _x <- mkStringSymbol "x"
            _y <- mkStringSymbol "y"

            a' <- mkStringSymbol "a"
            ac' <- mkStringSymbol "ac"
            b' <- mkStringSymbol "b"
            bc' <- mkStringSymbol "bc"

            is_a <- mkStringSymbol "is-a"
            is_ac <- mkStringSymbol "is-ac"
            is_b <- mkStringSymbol "is-b"
            is_bc <- mkStringSymbol "is-bc"

            b <- mkConstructor b' is_b [] --Should contain an X
            bc <- mkConstructor bc' is_bc []
            y <- mkDatatype y' [b, bc]

            a  <- mkConstructor a' is_a [(_x, Just y, 0)]
            ac <- mkConstructor ac' is_ac []
            x <- mkDatatype x' [a, ac]

            a_v' <- mkStringSymbol "a_v"
            b_v' <- mkStringSymbol "b_v"
            a_v <- mkConst a_v' x
            b_v <- mkConst b_v' y

            [a_func, _] <- getDatatypeSortConstructors x
            a_b_v <- mkApp a_func [b_v]

            assert =<< mkEq a_v a_b_v

            solverCheckAndGetModel
```

Note that the constructor b, of datatype Y, is incorrect in my Haskell implementation.  It is missing the argument of type X.  However, I cannot directly include the sort X, because it has not yet been declared.  But if I swap the order of the definitions of X and Y, I clearly run into the same problem, just reversed (i.e., I then need to, but cannot, reference Y in X.)

Based on the definition of MkConstructor on this page (which concerns the C api, not the Haskell api):

http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html#a2a421919ab766bf028ec422723b42e37

I think maybe I have to pass something of the form [(symbol, Nothing, #)] to mkConstructor, where # is some non-zero identifier of datatype X.  But I'm not 100% sure that's right, and even if it is, I don't know how to obtain #.  Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A rather wild guess: This Z3 monad has a [`MonadFix` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3-4.1.0/docs/Z3-Monad.html); it may well be possible to use it to specify the mutually recursive definition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've never used MonadFix before, so perhaps I'm just missing something, but unfortunately I'm not sure it can solve this issue.  Because to correctly create the constructor for X using it, you must create Y, but to do that you need X... and so on.  It can never finish evaluating a function... but again perhaps I'm using it wrong... thanks for the idea, I'll try and play around with it a bit more later.

Comment: Sorry -- I pasted the wrong link in that comment. I meant to link to [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonadFix), which gives a few usage examples for `MonadFix`. I'm specifically thinking of the second example there, the one with two nodes that point at each other. It is possible that something in that vein will work for your use case (it will mainly depend on whether `mkConstructor` can build the value without looking "into" the reference to the other value).

Comment: I see, thanks.  It's certainly quite interesting... Since it's basically a (relatively direct, I think) wrapper around a C function, and it has to feed all the information into Z3, I suspect I might not benefit much from laziness.  Definitely I'll experiment with it though!  Again, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does `mkConstructor` has to look into the other values reference.  Thanks anyway though!